# how to use functions from a sub-module

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am confused about how to use functions from a sub module. For example, `numpy` has a submodule `linalg`, which contains a function `solve`, so I can do:

```
import numpy as np
np.linalg.solve(  # And then specify what I want to solve
```

Similarly, `scipy` has a subpackage `sparse`, which has a subpackage `linalg`, which has a function `spsolve`, yet I cannot do this:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
sp.linalg.spsolve( # And then whatever I want to solve
```

Why not? Shouldn't that work?

Comment: I don't see why you can't do this, what its the output message, your full instruction parameters?

Comment: What error does python output when you run the code?

Comment: Because `linalg` isn't available in `scipy.sparse` by default (see https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/master/scipy/sparse/__init__.py); you need `from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve`.

Comment: So why isn't `linalg` 'available' in `scipy.sparse` by default? What is set up different than in the `numpy` case? Just trying to understand. I know how to import spsolve, but I am teaching this to students and I don't have a good argument why the syntax works for `numpy` and it doesn't for `scipy.sparse`. Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: That's just a decision the makers have made, presumably it takes too long to load *everything* up-front so they have left some things out. See e.g. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/api.html, where `scipy.sparse.linalg` is mentioned specifically.

Comment: Thanks, Jon, that clears it up.